# Helm template isn't outuput expected value in ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I have the following template in config_map.yaml and helm values file.

In the cm template I have the following:

```
"VARKEY": {{.Values.VARKEY}}
```

In the values file I have the following:

```
"VARKEY": ["var1", "var2"]
```

When I create the ConfigMap or use helm template to test it I recieve the following.

```
"VARKEY": [var1 var2]
```

My application is expecting the cm value as follows.
Expected output:

```
"VARKEY": ["var1", "var2"]
```

How the expected output could be achieved

How I Could achieve the expected output, why did Helm is changing the data from the values file?

Actually, the configmap is using a json format set like this because the app is expecting conf.json file. And the problem appears as described initially in the post format of the value is changed by helm. Which is the best way to be fixed? squote function?

## templates/configmap.yaml

```
data:
  conf.json: |+
    {
       {{ .Values.VARKEY }},
       "{{ .Values.OTHERKEY_STRING }}",
       {{ .Values.ANOTHERKEY_INT }}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are a YAML list, and you're seeing that structure in your template code.  A ConfigMap's values are always strings, and you also need to make sure the output is a YAML string and not some other sort of structure.

One answer is to explicitly quote the value in `values.yaml`, and then you'll have the output you expect (with some care).

```yaml
# values.yaml
VARKEY: '["var1", "var2"]'
```

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
data:
  VARKEY: {{ squote .Values.VARKEY }}
```

Another option is to continue to accept the value in list syntax, but then explicitly render it to JSON in the output.  Just writing out `{{ $someList }}` will get you a default format from the Go templating engine which isn't especially useful; you need to use the [`toJson` template function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) to get JSON syntax back out.

```yaml
# values.yaml
"VARKEY": ["var1", "var2"]

# equivalently (with a different name, but same structure)
varKey:
  - var1
  - var2
```

```yaml
# templates/configmap.yaml
data:
  VARKEY: |-
{{ .Values.VARKEY | toJson | indent 4 }}
```

In the last example I am explicitly using YAML block-scalar syntax.  This normally creates a multi-line string (and pairs well with `toYaml` should you need that).  Of the various quoting and escaping mechanisms in YAML, it's the only one that's not sensitive to the contents of the string, provided you put a consistent amount of whitespace at the start of each line (that is, `indent` it).  Using `squote` to put the string in single quotes is sensitive to the string itself containing single quotes, and similarly with `quote` and double quotes.

Comment: Actually, the configmap is using a json  format set like this.

# templates/configmap.yaml

data:
  conf.json: |+
    {
       {{ .Values.VARKEY }},
       "{{ .Values.OTHERKEY_STRING }}",
       {{ .Values.ANOTHERKEY_INT }}"
    }

Comment: Helm includes functions to construct lists and dictionaries, and you might construct the object in a variable using `dict` and similar functions and then dump that out via `toJson`.  That will guarantee the quoting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining VARKEY in the 'values' as a string directly, rather than in the form of a string array.

values.yaml

```yaml
VARKEY: '["var1", "var2"]'
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
"VARKEY": {{ .Values.VARKEY }}
```

output

```yaml
"VARKEY": ["var1", "var2"]
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working this way  exactly as expected :)